# using function in google bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-function

I am trying to use sql function in my BigQuery query :

```
SELECT FORMAT("%T", NET.HOST(resolved_urls.url)) AS host, FROM [tableName] LIMIT 1000
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: 2.15 - 2.55: Unrecognized function format

I am getting these error for every sql function i am trying to use.

Any Idea ? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those new functions are supported by BigQuery Standard SQL only

Try below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT FORMAT("%T", NET.HOST(resolved_urls.url)) AS host, FROM tableName LIMIT 1000
```

Also note: in Standard SQL you use `tableName` and not [tableName]